# How to calculate the cardano network throughput?

Tags: ouroboros, transactions-per-second

I've been searching about the Cardano's network throughput in TPS and read in some place that is about 1000, in other place that is 250.

But when I try to actually calculate it using the average transaction size (613 Bytes) and the max block size (65536 Bytes) I get that a block can hold about 107 transactions, knowing that the activeSlotCoefficient is 0.05. I can conclude that the throughput is:

107 * 0.05 = 5.35 TPS
Which seems like I'm doing something wrong.

How do I actually calculate the throughput, and what am I doing wrong?